# Broadcasting IM in LYNC 2013

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, lync-2013, ucma

I want to send same Instant Message (IM) to multiple users in different conversation on LYNC 2013. 
I tried looking into LYNC SDK samples, but did not got any fruitful solution.

Since I am naive with C# , .net code. Any leads will be appreciated.

I'm not sure what samples from Lync SDK should be modified, to broadcast IM to different users.

Comment: how about showing some code that you have tried to implement to accomplish your function, so that we can better understand where the error is ?

Comment: There are LYNC Code samples available. I tried to modify 'Start Conversation' code. It will ask participant IM ID, and will generate conversation with it. But I want same conversation for multiple participants. Code is available on https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Lync-2013-Start-an-IM-27951440/view/SourceCode#content